# Simulate Mouse Hover using user32.dll with C# on flash window

Tags: c#, .net

I need to send a mouse Hover message to a particular point in a window(window is a flash program) without moving the actual mouse.

I am using mouse_event for my left click.

At the moment I am moving the actual mouse over the position I want to simulate the hover event on the window) but then I don't have control over my mouse any more and doing stuff like stopping the program is very tough since program has all control over mouse.

Answer (score 0):

I have written something where i get cursor position before and restore it after the click. Seems to be working.

I don't know if I can avoid the cursor movement completely as that would be the absolute solution.

```
public static void LeftClick(Point position)
    {
        Point cursorPosition;
        GetCursorPos(out cursorPosition);

        MoveMouseTo(position.X, position.Y);
        mouse_event((int)(MouseEventFlags.LEFTDOWN | MouseEventFlags.LEFTUP | MouseEventFlags.ABSOLUTE), position.X, position.Y, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

        SetCursorPos(cursorPosition.X, cursorPosition.Y);
    }
```